# TapeJS won't recognize all test files inside expanded (**) subfolder

Tags: javascript, testing

I'm trying to separate tests into different subfolders
E.g:

```
- tests
-- unit-tests
--- services
--- gateways
-- integration-tests
-- other
```

When I try to run tests inside some of these, it won't fetch all test files for the ones that have subsequent sub-folders.
E.g:

```
tape ./tests/unit-tests/**/*.test.js
```

Tried wrapping the path between " and ', but none have worked.

Anyone knows what am I missing?